# Convert RgbImage into Vec<[u8; 3]>

Tags: image, rust

I have an `RgbImage` but for the gaussian blur algorithm I need to convert it to `Vec<[u8; 3]>`. I managed to do this before using:

```
let img: Vec<u8> = img.into_raw();
let mut new: Vec<[u8; 3]> = vec![];
for (r, g, b) in img.into_iter().tuples() {
    new.push([r, g, b]);
}
```

But in my new project for some reason I get the error `no method named tuples found for struct std::vec::IntoIter in the current scope`. I'm not sure why this is happening but I think there is a much better way to do it anyway.

Comment: [`.tuples()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuples) comes from the `itertools` crate, which you probably haven't added as a dependency in your new project.

Comment: @cdhowie Yes thanks! I'm not sure how I missed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the crate [`itertools`](https://lib.rs/crates/itertools) for [`tuples()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuples).

Or you can use std's [`chunks_exact()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact):

```rust
for color in img.chunks_exact(3) {
    new.push(color.try_into().unwrap());
}
```